# double to unsigned int / char

Tags: c++, floating-point, unsigned

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541200/casting-double-to-unsigned-int), that:

According to C99 §6.3.1.4 footnote 50:

> The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is
>   converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of real
>   floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of
>   portable real floating values is (−1, Utype_MAX+1).

Now, I am interested in the subtle difference (this time for **C++ 03**!) between:

```
double d1 = 257;
double d2 = -2;

unsigned char c1 = d1; // undefined, since d1 > 256
unsigned char c2 = d2; // undefined, since d2 < -1
```

and

```
double d1 = 257;
double d2 = -2;

unsigned int i1 = d1; // defined, since d1 <= 2^32
unsigned int i2 = d2; // still undefined, right?

unsigned char c1 = i1; // defined, modulo 2^8, so c1 == 1
```

So the first `c1` and the second `c1` are not guaranteed to compare as equal, right? Is the citation from above also valid for C++03, or are there other rules?

**Edit:**

and for making `c2` defined (for `-(2^31-1) <= d2 < 0`) would this be necessary to do?

```
double d2 = -2;
int sign = (d2<0 ? -1 : 1);

unsigned char c2 = sign * (int)abs(d2); // defined, c2 == 2^8-2 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same rule applies for C++. (However, I am going by a 2010 draft of the C++ standard; C++ 2003 is old. Also, I am using N3092, not the official draft.) Clause 4.9, paragraph 1 says “The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.”

Unsigned integer arithmetic does wrap; it is performed modulo 1 more than the maximum value of the type. However, this applies to arithmetic within the type. Conversion from floating-point to unsigned integer is not part of this.

Your code for converting `d2` seems more complicated than necessary. If `d2` is within the range of an `int`, you could simply use `unsigned char c2 = (int) d2;`. (Although conversion from `int` to `unsigned int` is also outside homogeneous unsigned integer arithmetic, the specification for this conversion does say it is reduced the same way unsigned integer arithmetic is.)

Comment: FYI, that wording is also found verbatim in `[C++11: 4.9/1]` (also in n3690, which is the C++1y draft from last May).

Comment: Thanks for answer. For `int` to `unsigned int` conversion there is never a rearranging of bits, right? And for `unsigned int` to `unsigned char` there are always discarded the higher order bis, right? So if `d` would be within range of `char` (e.g. -2), then `unsigned char ca = (char)d` and `unsigned char cb = (int)d` would always be equal?

Comment: There are few guarantees about the bit layout of `int`, as 1s complement may even be legal (!) (unsure, but of little practical import)