# What's going on with typecasting in C?

Tags: c, low-level

I get what typecasting in C is doing at a high level. I get that sometimes this is done implicitly, and sometimes is required to be done explicitly. However I don't know how this is happening in low level:

Suppose that `GetSignal` returns an `enum` type.

```
 uint8 outValue;
 f32_t iValue;
 iValue = (f32_t)GetSignal();
 outValue = (uint8)((i32_t)iValue);
```

My question is what is going on here. I have no idea how the bits are being reorganised after all of these typecasting.

Comment: Sometimes it's not really changing the bits, only telling the compiler "trust me" so it won't complain about what would otherwise be a type mismatch.

Comment: But what about suming two diferent types , for example when you try to sum a`float` and an `int` . They are both ordered in their respective registers with diferent standards , if the ALU tries to sum them as would sum 2 integers ,it would return a weird result. So my best guess is that some bit manipulation is being done

Comment: Yes, there are also cases of bit manipulation, and int-to-float (and the other way around) does instruct the compiler to turn int-smelling bits into the same numerical value with float-smelling bits, but this often happens without a cast because the compile can tell it has an int and a float and it needs to add them (as you suggest).

Comment: In your question it is not really possible to be specific without knowing what `f32_t` is an alias for.  The name (and the name of the function) would suggest that it is a single precision `float` and not an `enum` as you suggest.  That makes a significant difference to what that casting does.  Don't obfuscate the question by using `typedef` aliases that we have to guess at - use the actual data types of standard library type aliases.

Comment: Your _comment_ in response to @SteveFreidl is a different question  than that posed. SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.  Either post a new question or add it to the existing question if it is closely related.

Answer (score 4):

What a cast does is convert a value of one type to a value of another type.  What the *representation* of this value is for each given type depends on the type.

Suppose `GetSignal` returns an enum with an underlying value of 1.  As a 32 bit integer, its representation looks like this (assuming big-endian byte ordering, i.e. high-to-low):

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

This integer value of 1 is then converted via an explicit cast to `f32_t`.  Assuming that this type is represented as an IEEE 754 single precision floating point value, its representation (high-to-low) looks like this:

```
00111111 10000000 00000000 00000000
```

And this representation is stored in `iValue`.

Then `iValue` is cast to `i32_t`.  So the `float` value 1 with the above IEEE754 floating point representation is converted to the `int` value 1 with this representation:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Which is the same as what `GetSignal` returned.  This value is then cast to type `uint8` which has this representation:

```
00000001
```

And that representation is stored in `outValue`.

Regarding your comment about adding a `float` and an `int`, the **usual arithmetic conversion** rules dictate that the value with type `int` is first implicitly converted to type `float`, then the two `float` values can be added and the result has type `float`.

Comment: re: `(uint8)(i32_t)a_float` - FP->int conversion where the value doesn't fit in the integer type is Undefined Behaviour; going to int32_t first and *then* truncating to uint8_t is well-defined.  [Is the behaviour of casting a negative double to unsigned int defined in the C standard? Different behaviour on ARM vs. x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10541200)  - would also apply to a float larger than `255` which would also not fit in `uint8_t`.  So if you have a float and want to truncate the integer part to a narrow type, convert to a wide-enough integer type first.